# Swift network request and JSON Serialization error

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am just practicing with swift networking and JSON serialization api from a tutorial I saw online. The request and serialization are both successful but yet I do receive a console error.

The project is a swift package execution with library along side it.

**Networking Code**

```
import Foundation
import Basic
import SPMUtility
import libjetpack
import Files

struct Course: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let link: String
    let imageUrl: String
}

let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/course")!)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")

var sema = DispatchSemaphore( value: 0)
let taskWithRequest = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
        print("No data")
        return
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let course = try decoder.decode(Course.self, from: data)
        print(course)
    } catch let decodeError as NSError {
        print("Decoder error: \(decodeError.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    sema.signal()
}

taskWithRequest.resume()
sema.wait()
```

**Package.swift**

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "jetpack",
    products: [
        .library(name: "libjetpack", targets: ["libjetpack"]),
        .executable(name: "jetpack", targets: ["jetpack"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager.git", from: "0.4.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/johnsundell/files.git", from: "3.1.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/jpsim/Yams.git", from: "2.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi.git", from: "3.1.1"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/honghaoz/Ji.git", from: "5.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna.git", from: "5.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup.git", from: "2.2.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "libjetpack",
            dependencies: ["Files", "Yams"]),
        .target(
            name: "jetpack",
            dependencies: ["libjetpack", "SPMUtility", "Fuzi", "Kanna", "Ji", "SwiftSoup"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "jetpackTests",
            dependencies: ["jetpack"]),
    ]
)
```

When I run the code I get the following error message.

```
2019-08-21 16:01:44.118728-0400 jetpack[37216:2570604] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=20, pid=37216
2019-08-21 16:01:44.118841-0400 jetpack[37216:2570604] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: jetpack[37216]/0#-1 LF=0
Course(id: 1, name: "Instagram Firebase", link: "https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course/instagram-firebase", imageUrl: "https://letsbuildthatapp-videos.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/04782e30-d72a-4917-9d7a-c862226e0a93")
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Please let me know how to correct the error.

Comment: None of these packages needed for this task.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I know that I was just copying everything. They are just packages I was playing around with. The issue is really the error not the packages. I just wanted to give a complete environment. But thank you for your comment.